# two itunes apple accounts

Tags: itunes

i have been using my itunes account on my phone to buy music, but when i went to log in on my PC it wouldn't work(i was using the wrong email) when i went to make a new one i put in an itunes voucher that had been given to me and created that account on the email that i thought my original account was on. but i have now managed to find my other email and itunes account. is there a way that i could transfer the money from one account to the other?

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no cross-pollination of Apple IDs.

Best you could probably do is set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) & invite your other account into that 'family'